# Streaming output of x264_encoder_encode

Tags: c++, udp, streaming, x264, libx264

how can I stream the output of x264_encoder_encode over UDP?

This is my Init_x264-function:

```
x264_param_t param;
x264_param_default_preset(&param, "veryfast", "zerolatency");
param.i_threads = 1;
param.i_width = width;
param.i_height = height;
param.i_fps_num = 30;
param.i_fps_den = 1;

param.i_keyint_max = 30;
param.b_intra_refresh = 1;

param.rc.i_rc_method = X264_RC_CRF;
param.rc.f_rf_constant = 25;
param.rc.f_rf_constant_max = 35;

param.b_annexb = 1;
param.b_repeat_headers = 1;

param.i_log_level = X264_LOG_DEBUG;

x264_param_apply_profile(&param, "baseline");

encoder = x264_encoder_open(&param);

picIn = new x264_picture_t;
picOut = new x264_picture_t;
x264_picture_alloc(picIn, X264_CSP_I420, width, height);
x264_encoder_parameters(encoder, &param);
```

Now instead of saving the output of x264_encoder_encode to disk (using fwrite) I tried to just send it over UDP to my destination. I tried to play it with avplay, but it fails:

```
[h264 @ 0x7f83f0012e80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f83f0012e80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f83f0012e80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f83f0012e80] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f83f0012e80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f83f0012e80] no frame!
```

With vlc I got different error messages, mostly about missing headers.

Comment: On does not normally stream H.264 bitstream as is, instead it is fragmented into UDP-friendly data blocks according to e.g. requirements of RTP protocol, and [RTP Payload Format for H.264 Video](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6184).

Comment: Those's errors are Ok. With param.b_repeat_headers = 1 the SPS/PPS  repeats every keyframe (x264 default is a keyframe every ever 250 frames, or when a scene change occurs). If you join a stream in progress, the player may receive some frames that reference an SPS/PPS that it has not seen yet. Those frames will be dropped until the next keyframe is seen. Are you putting the stream into a container (like a transport stream?) Because VLC can not play an annex b stream directly.

Comment: All I do is to call x264_encoder_encode() and udpsocket.send(). There is no container. (If I save it to disk instead, vlc/avplay is able to play it.)

Comment: @user2660369. Did you got it working, any example code please,, as i am also facing this situation